# Passing Android Acceleromter values from MainActivity to My GameView class

Tags: android, class, accelerometer, dynamic-variables

I am working on a game involving measuring accelerometer values and manipulating my character's position based on those values. I am only working with the X axis. I initiate my accelerometer manager in my main activity, but I need to use these values in another class. Obviously these values are constantly changing. How could I pass these values to my GameView class?

Answer (score 0):

You can save them as static members of your activity, or pass them to GameView class each time there's a change in them (new value)

Comment: Hm, how could I pass the value only when it changes?

Answer (score 0):

If you've used a sensorlistener you might think about moving that logic to the GameView class. Not totally sure without looking at your code though. Do you have any samples?

Comment: I have used a sensor listener, I thought about moving it over. Let me try that. I would still like to know how to pass dynamic variables correctly and efficiently though.

Comment: Is the sensorlistener only being used for the GameView class? Is there any reason that you have it in the main activity?

Comment: Honestly, no, but I am not sure how to implement it in my GameView class. Most of the functions are not active in my workable scope in that class.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it the Android way? :)

When you implement a touch listener, you do something set like this:

```
myView.setOnTouchlistener(this):
```

This tells the view to call you back when it's touched.  Here's how to do your own:

Define an interface and use a callback to let the class know that a value has changed.

```
public interface AccelerometerUpdateListener {
    void onUpdate(int arg1, string arg2); ..<----add arguments you want to pass back
}
```

In your Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AccelerometerUpdateListener {

ArrayList<AccelerometerUpdateListener > listeners = new ArrayList<AccelerometerUpdateListener >();

...


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    ...
    myGameClass.setResponseReceivedistener(this);
    ...
}

public void setUpdateListener(AccelerometerUpdateListener listener){
    if (!listeners.contains(listener){
        listeners.add(listener);
    }
}

public void removeUpdateListener(AccelerometerUpdateListener listener){
    if (listeners.contains(listener){
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }
}
```

When you update the values

```
for (AccelerometerUpdateListener listener:listeners){
   listener.onUpdate(arg1, arg2);
}
```

In your receiving class:

```
public class MyGameClass implements AccelerometerUpdateListener {

...

@Override
public void onUpdate(int arg1, string arg2){
    // do whatever you need to do
}
```

All from memory so please excuse typos.

Comment: I think you've lost me a little. Care to walk me through this?